# Filter data in excel and paste into template

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT: The workbook contains a lot of formulas. I am thinking a better way may be to have a macro sort through the data, but have the current workbook save as a new file for each business, with the extra rows deleted. So it would have some sort of if/then statement saying "if column A does not contain the name SAM from row 1 through 20000, delete the row". That way at the end I would have a file with just SAM's data and all the formulas would remain intact? But I would need this to run multiple times for each name in column A and save each as a new workbook.

I have a large excel file with thousands of rows of data that contain column info such as business name, order date, order number, sales total, etc. Each business has multiple rows of data and I am trying to filter the rows and save new workbooks so each business has its own file with just their data in it. I found a great macro that was able to do this, but the original workbook also has other sheets that use formulas to auto populate tables based on the business data found in the sheet I want to be filtered. I need these sheets to also be copied over into each business's new workbook while keeping the formulas functioning correctly. I made a template file, and am hoping there is a way to alter the macro I used to filter the data so that instead of saving into a new workbook, it can paste and save each business's filtered data into the template. Here is the macro I used...

```
Public Type BROWSEINFO
    hOwner As Long
    pidlRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

'32-bit API declarations
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
  Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) _
  As Long

Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) As Long


Function GetDirectory(Optional Msg) As String
    Dim bInfo As BROWSEINFO
    Dim path As String
    Dim r As Long, x As Long, pos As Integer

'   Root folder = Desktop
    bInfo.pidlRoot = 0&

'   Title in the dialog
    If IsMissing(Msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Select a folder."
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = Msg
    End If

'   Type of directory to return
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1

'   Display the dialog
    x = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)

'   Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetDirectory = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetDirectory = ""
    End If
End Function

Sub Lapta()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Integer, i As Long, iStart As Long, iEnd As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, iCol As Integer, t As Date, Prefix As String
Dim sh As Worksheet, Master As String, Folder As String, Fname As String
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Application.InputBox("Click in the column to extract by", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
iCol = r.Column
t = Now
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    Master = .Name
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Sort Key1:=Cells(2, iCol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    iStart = 2
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, iCol).Value <> .Cells(i + 1, iCol).Value Then
            iEnd = i
            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Name = .Cells(iStart, iCol).Value
            On Error GoTo 0
            ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastCol)).Value = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).Value
            .Range(.Cells(iStart, 1), .Cells(iEnd, LastCol)).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A2")
            iStart = iEnd + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Completed in " & Format(Now - t, "hh:mm:ss.00"), vbInformation
If MsgBox("Do you want to save the separated sheets as workbooks", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
    Folder = "Select the folder to save the workbooks"
    Folder = GetDirectory(Folder)
    If Folder = "" Then Exit Sub
    Prefix = InputBox("Enter a prefix (or leave blank)")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> Master Then
            sh.Copy
            Fname = Folder & "\" & Prefix & sh.Name & ".xls"
            If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls)", _
                Title:=Fname & " exists - select file to save as")
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
     Next sh
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you not getting any errors? FYI you need to also qualify `Cells()` with the worksheet, like you do `Range`.  Although you're using the Activesheet, it's better if you do that, i.e. `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1), ws.Cells(1, LastCol)...` wherever `Cells()` occurs.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "column info"? The first row? Copying other sheets should be straight forward. How exactly is the interaction with the other sheets formulars? What information do the formulas need to work properly?

Comment: By column info, I just meant that each row has multiple cells of information (row 1 has info through column BE). I have three sheets total in my template- a sheet called Summary, a sheet called Table, and a sheet called Data (which is where I need the data to be inserted). The Summary and Table sheets use functions such as averaging the "Sales" column in the Data sheet. I'm not very familiar with VBA, and I was unable to find a post about copying and pasting data that does what I need.